# USB 3.0 HDD not working

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1

I'm using Windows 8.1

- When I plug in my brand-new-awesome 2TB Adata HDD in a USB 3.0 port,
  it isn't recognized by the OS
- When I try to use a USB 2.0 port, it works well
- The drivers seem to be up-to-date

How can I get it working with USB 3.0?

Comment: This might work:

http://superuser.com/questions/719079/usb-3-0-ports-function-as-usb-2-0-ports-on-windows-7-with-an-intel-usb-3-0-xhci/719080#719080 even though that answer is for Win7

Comment: It **might** work, and actually it doesn't work: I've tried to enter BIOS but the settings show that USB 3.0 are enabled; I've downloaded the Intel drivers, but no result

Comment: Do other devices work in the USB 3.0 port(s)?

Comment: Neither the simple Logitech mouse receiver!

Answer (score 0):

Try a different port, I'm sure the drive is compatible with USB 2.0.  Obviously not the ideal solution but it would at least allow you test to make sure it's not the drive that is the problem.

Comment: Yes! It indeed works in USB 2.0 port! but it's **extremely** slow!

Comment: I wonder if the cable you have is a usb 2 cable?  I think usb 3 has more wires in it.  You're probably using the one it came with, but just in case you're not or it didn't come with one there's that.  I'd try uninstalling the usb ports and reinstalling with drivers off the boards manufacturer site.  It could be that windows update installed drivers that maybe it shouldn't have.  Also if that doesn't work do the same process but see if windows update has drivers.  Sometimes windows update drivers fixes things for me, it's weird.  Is the board in warranty?  Might be able to replace it to fix it.

Comment: ahah ;) just moved to ubuntu 14.04, yet the problem is still alive..no, the cable is a 3.0 one

Comment: Are you using ubuntu in a vm or a fresh install?  Because if you're using it through a vm, the problem won't fix itself.  Vm's rely on the host os having a device working in order for the vm to detect it and use it.  Could make a live cd maybe and boot up from it but I'm not sure if a live cd would have all the drivers you'd need.  Maybe?