# USB 3.0 ports function as USB 2.0 ports on Windows 7 -- trying to fix via DeviceMgr & downloads from Intel website

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, device-manager

My question is actually a follow-up to the question-and-answer poisted by a fellow at this superuser URL, [USB 3.0 ports function as USB 2.0 ports on Windows 7 with an Intel USB 3.0 xHCI Controller](https://superuser.com/questions/719079/usb-3-0-ports-function-as-usb-2-0-ports-on-windows-7-with-an-intel-usb-3-0-xhci)

The specs for my computer are:  HP Pavilion dv7-6b32us Laptop Core i7 2670QM 2.20GHz, 4GB DDR3, 640GB HDD ,Win 7 Prem.

As I understand it, in order to verify that my computer's designated 'USB 3.0' ports will actually interface with 'USB 3.0 flash-drives' at USB 3.0 speeds, it is necessary for **iusb3hcs** to appear when I select **Device lower filters** in the details of the "PCI bus" device, via Device Manager.

As this screenshot indicates, that does not seem to be the case for me:

[image: "iusb3hcs" nor "Device Lower Filters" does not appear when I select "details" of the "PCI bus" device, via Device Manager]

To that end, as suggested at the previous Superuser question-and-answer, I tried going to the [Intel website via this link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software%20Products&ProductLine=Chipset%20Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20USB%203.0%20eXtensible%20Host%20Controller%20Driver). *(click to see)*

There are 4 downloads being offered by the website, but how do I determine which of these 4 offered downloads is the appropriate one for me to download?

[image: There are 4 downloads being offered by Intel at this URL, but how does one determine which of these 4 offered downloads is the appropriate one for them]

Many thanks for any help that can be offered.

Comment: Pick the download that matches your chipset, also download the latest by date.

Comment: Errr... how might I determine which is my chipset? I did find something called 'Intel Chipset Identification Utility' via https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18498/Intel-Chipset-Identification-Utility , but, it's stated as being only compatible with 32-bit operating systems. I am on Windows7-home-premium-64bit.

Comment: [For 64bit use the driver update utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect)

Comment: @moab ok, I typed up my reasoning at this link. http://pasted.co/d0f83a99 the password is superuser

Answer (score 1):

Sigh... well, a slight update on the situation, and this corresponds to the followup thread located [here](https://superuser.com/questions/934840/how-do-i-identify-what-is-my-intel-chipset-on-a-windows-7-home-premium-64bit), too.

None of the ideas worked, despite spending HOURS trying to get the USB3.0 ports to actually operate at USB3.0 speeds.

**I mention this as a warning to others that might be having a similar issue-- solving the problem could potentially eat up a LOT of time.**

One of these days, I might attempt to fix the problem again. In the meantime, it's more pragmatic to just settle for USB2.0 speed.

All the same, my many thanks to the people that tried to help.

Also, the computer model I was trying to fix this on was a HP Pavilion dv7-4295us notebook (or something very similar).

Comment: Any updates? I bought an Oculus Quest 2 VR device, which only works correctly when detected as a USB 3.0 device, but my system (Windows 10 with 4 USB 3.0 ports) keeps detecting it as a USB 2.0 device. Same things happens with an external USB 3.0 HDD. 
In BIOS I disabled "Legacy USB Support" but it did not help. I am stuck...

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, you have a sandy-bridge CPU, which usually pairs with 6-series chipset. And there is NO USB 3.0 support on the Intel 6-series chipset. Its possible to pair 7-series with this CPU but I highly doubt so.

So you need to find the proper USB 3.0 driver for the 3rd party controller used in the laptop. Go to manufacturer's website and carefully check the download section.

Comment: _Sound of banging head against desk repeatedly_ Sweet monkey jesus... SERIOUSLY? The reason I can't get USB3.0 to work, IS BECAUSE OF MY CPU & Chipset? Yeah, I checked and found out that my chipset is Generation-6, btw. But... why did Hewlett Packard include USB3.0 ports (I know they're USB3.0 because they have a blue color to their interior) IN THE FIRST PLACE?? Seriously, if you can give me an answer, please do!

Comment: I _did_ catch your mention of recommending finding the proper 'USB 3.0 3rd party controller used in the laptop.' Would you be able to scout out the answer for me? I ask this because: (1)I have been left **exhausted** by this problem after spending **hours** on it; and also (2)i THINK that I remember attempting something like you suggested, to no avail. All of my pertinent specs and info should be visible in the posts above. Thanks in advance if you can help with this, @Chric-C

Comment: @MercWithMouth what's the exact model of the laptop? however I noticed that you have the USB3 ports working just below the speed, this indicates that the driver is already loaded otherwise it wouldn't be recognized at all. And is there any USB related settings in BIOS you can try?

Comment: Hi @ChrisC. I'm very grateful for you offering to help me out. Well, I took a closer look at the laptop, and this is what I found in the sales specs that I'm copying & pasting here: **HP Pavilion dv7-6b32us** Laptop Core i7 2670QM 2.20GHz, 4GB DDR3, 640GB HDD ,Win 7 Prem. I did already try to find a USB-setting in the BIOS, to no avail. Lastly, you said `however I noticed that you have the USB3 ports working just below the speed, this indicates that the driver is already loaded otherwise it wouldn't be recognized at all`. I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?